# Attaching a lav mic to a boom

Tags: lavalier, microphone, boom-pole

This basically is the age old problem of sing-operator video run-and-gun situations.

My employer has given me 2 lav mics and wants documentary style 3-person interviews to be done with them, I have no budget to purchase an audio recorder, additional mics or anything for that matter but I do have a boom attachment that can fit onto the tripod.

The 3rd person is actually myself as the interviewer behind the camera with 2-people in front, so I can pin a mic to myself no problem. The mics actually work surprisingly well when placed up to around 2 meters from the sound source but of course they will need to be much closer in the field.

So the only thing I can work out is to attach 1 of the lav mics to the boom pole attached to the tripod but I cannot find an elegant way to attach the lav mic to the boom pole or traditional mic holder that goes with the boom pole. 
I am not allowed to use any tape or cable ties and the mount must look professional.

Does anyone know of any technique or accessory that can do this? I'm thinking some clamps will do the trick but I'm pretty sure the boss will tell me to take them off so before I go down this path I want a better solution or at least a back up solution.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there an chance that you can ADR your questions later (in post)?

If yes, I'd attach the two lavs to the 2 people in front of the camera, since they are the point of interest and record your questions in post production. 
While doing the actual interview you could place a smartphone (or dictaphone,etc.) unobtrusive nearby yourself. Nobody will notice that.The audio quality won't be good, but that way you make sure, that you don't forget your lines later in the post.

Comment: Thanks for that @Michael, I was hoping to avoid wiring the subjects but there doesn't seem to be much of an option. ADR the questions in post seems to be the best way to go unfortunately, my smartphone should do the trick. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

How necessary is it to have your questions recorded and a part of the final product?
Can the interviewee's not answer the question by repeating the question within their answer (if that makes sense, I have forgotten the term)?

Maybe it is just me, but it feels a bit odd to have your questions recorded and you not on camera.

Alternatively, shoot yourself for reaction/question shots afterwards, using your smartphone/dictaphone for word-by-word reference with a lav hooked on you?
This is assuming ADR is not an option and you are just sending the materials elsewhere for post work.

Comment: Thanks for your input @chromasy, I cannot rely on the interview subjects to answer the questions as part of the answer so I think using my cell phone to record myself and then have the questions added in post if needed will be the way to go. 

It is a true run-and-gun situation as I will have between 1-2 minutes in each location for set-up and interview, I was hoping to avoid having to wire my subjects but there doesn't seem to be much of an alternative with what I have. 

Thanks again! 